# Easiest way to solve a system using LU decomposition in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

I hope someone can come up with a simpler way thank what I am thinking to solve this system using the LU decomposition of a matrix.

I found U and then took the inverse of the elementary matrix to get L. Therefore..
A=LU
But, to solve the matrix, I need Ax = b, so technically, x = (LU) ^ -1 * b.
This expanded comes to x = U^-1 * L^-1 * b.
This method, I would need to find the inverse of U and then the inverse of L and multiply everything to get the answer to the system. Is this the most efficient way? I can't use a calculator.

[image]

Comment: Can you briefly explain?

Answer (score 1):

Yes to solve a linear system of equations of the form ${\bf A} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{b}$ using the LU decomposition method, you follow the following steps

1. Decompose the coefficient matrix $$ {\bf A} = {\bf L}\, { \bf U}$$ where the diagonals of ${\bf L}$ are 1.
2. Solve the outer problem ${\bf L}\underbrace{{\bf U}\boldsymbol{x}}_{\boldsymbol{z}}=\boldsymbol{b}$, or ${\bf L}\boldsymbol{z}=\boldsymbol{b}$  by substitution starting from the 1st row and going down $$ z_i = b_i - \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} L_{ik} z_k$$
3. Solve the inner problem ${\bf U}\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{z}$ by substitution starting from the last row and going up $$x_i = \frac{1}{U_{ii}} \left( z_i - \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} U_{ik} x_k \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I derived two equations and expanded them out to solve.

I took Ax = B
I took A = LU

Then LUx = B, Let Ux = y, so Ly = B for y
Then Ux = y for solving for x.

Comment: Correct, no need to calculate the inverses. Since $L$ and $U$ are in triangular form, solving $Ly = B$ and $Ux = y$ is easy.